# Rolling average using groupby and varying window length

Tags: r, rolling-computation

I'm trying to create a rolling average of a column based on an ID column and a measurement time label in R, but I am having a lot of trouble with it.

Here is what my dataframe looks like:

```
ID Measurement Value

A    1           10

A    2           12

A    3           14

B    1           10

B    2           12

B   3           14

B   4           10
```

The problem is that I have measurement counts varying from 9 to 76 for each ID so I haven't found a solution that will create a column of a rolling average for each ID while handling the varying window length.

My goal is a dataframe like this:

```
ID Measurement Value Average

A    1           10 NA

A    2           12 11

A    3           14 12

B    1           10 NA

B    2           12 11

B   3           14  12 

B   4           10 11.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses no packages. It calculates the cumulative average by ID except that for `Measurement` equal to 1 it forces the average to be `NA`.

```
transform(DF, Avg = ave(Value, ID, FUN = cumsum) / 
   ifelse(Measurement == 1, NA, Measurement))
```

giving:

```
  ID Measurement Value  Avg
1  A           1    10   NA
2  A           2    12 11.0
3  A           3    14 12.0
4  B           1    10   NA
5  B           2    12 11.0
6  B           3    14 12.0
7  B           4    10 11.5
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "ID Measurement Value
A    1           10
A    2           12
A    3           14
B    1           10
B    2           12
B    3           14
B    4           10"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

With your data:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
   group_by(Id) %>%
   mutate(Avrg = cumsum(Value)/(1:n()))

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   Id [2]
  Id    Measurement Value  Avrg
  <chr>       <int> <int> <dbl>
1 A               1    10  10  
2 A               2    12  11  
3 A               3    14  12  
4 B               1    10  10  
5 B               2    12  11  
6 B               3    14  12  
7 B               4    10  11.5
```

Data:

```
structure(list(Id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
               Measurement = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
               Value = c(10L, 12L, 14L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 10L)
               ), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

P.S. I am pretty sure that the average of 10 is 10, not NA

Comment: valuable answer,facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(rolling_mean = cummean(Value))
```

First row will be mean of first value for each group (ID), not NA.